# checking data exists or not when editing the data in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem when editing data from the database.

this is my controller function

```
public function cek_nip_update()
{
    $this->load->model("model_dosen");
    $unique_id = $this->input->post('unique_id');
    $nip = $this->input->post('nip');
    $hasil_nip = $this->model_dosen->cek_nip($nip);
    $hasil_unik = $this->model_dosen->cek_unik($unique_id);
    $hasil_cek = $this->model_dosen->cek_nipp($nip,$unique_id);
    if (count($hasil_nip)==0)
    {
        echo 'gada'; 
    }
    else
    {
        if ($hasil_nip==$hasil_cek) {
            echo "gada";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ada";
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my model

```
public function cek_nip($nip)
    {
        $cek = $this->db->query("select nip from detail_dosen where nip='$nip'");
        return $cek->result();
    }

    public function cek_unik($unique_id)
    {
        $cek = $this->db->query("select nip from detail_dosen where unique_id='$unique_id'");
        return $cek->result();
    }

    public function cek_nipp($nip, $unique_id)
    {
        $cek = $this->db->query("select nip from detail_dosen where nip='$nip' and unique_id='$unique_id'");
        return $cek->result();
    }
```

The result I want is

1. When I type nip not exist, the span I make will not show something
2. When I type nip exits in the input, but with the same unique_id, the span will not show something
3. When I type nip exits in the input, with the different unique_id, the span will show "NIP is used by the other"

My code just works with number 1 condition, but when I type nip exists in the database, it shows "NIP is used by the other".

Can someone help me so my code can run like what I mentioned above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please tell me what exactly you want to do with this??

Comment: Explain the below points correctly. It is not good enough to understand.

Comment: You should explain correctly .but your question confusing us

Answer (score 0):

In your model try this

```
 return $this->db->get_where('detail_dosen', array('nip'=>$nip))->num_rows(); //it will give you number  of rows in return. so you can check like this if(count($hasil_nip) > 0) according to your  condition
```

if you want to get more result you can use

```
return $this->db->get_where('detail_dosen', array('nip'=>$nip))->result_array(); // OR row_array(); For this you can check like this if($hasil_nip){ //coding... }
```